# Remove duplicate file using bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have two files at path1 and path2 respectively.
I want to delete file at path2 if content of both the files are same.

I tried to achieve this using

```
cmp -s path1 path2 rm path2 ||echo "files are different"
```

but it doesn't work. Why not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing an `&&`.

```
cmp -s path1 path2 && rm path2 || echo "files are different"
```

I would use `if`/`else` rather than `&&`/`||` here. If `rm` happens to fail the above code will incorrectly say "files are different". Using `if`/`else` avoids this hiccup.

```
if cmp -s path1 path2; then
    rm path2
else
    echo "files are different"
fi
```

(As a general rule, only use `&&`/`||` if the command after `&&` always succeeds. If there's any chance it could fail stick with an explicit `if`/`else`.)